# Which is the correct form to create one to many relationships between two tables on a Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, data-modeling

I have a Oracle database in which I have two tables, RegistroPPL and Alias. One RegistroPPL can have multiple Aliases. Now, my question is, what is the right way to create this relationship, using a bridge table like this:
[image]

or creating a direct relationship like this

[image]

What is the best way to create one to many relationships according to the normalization rules, and how can I avoid redundant data?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the two-table design is used for one-to-many relationships.

The only reason I can think of you might want to use an intermediate table is if there's some reason to think that in the future this might become a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Most of the time we just want to enforce the relationship and the correct way to do that is with a foreign key between the child and the parent table. Occasionally we need to hold information about the actual relationship which might necessitate an intersection table, but even then I would question those attributes could be put on the child table.

Answer (score 0):

The question is:  can a single alias be used for multiple `registro_ppl`?  Presumably not.  Hence, you can get away with one row per alias.

There are some situations where a more complicated design might be needed -- for instance, if alias is a slowly changing dimension, then you might want `version_eff_dt` and `version_end_dt` to handle that.

However, the data model does not suggest having an intermediate table.